# CREATE TABLE statement in Oracle with the existence check

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ddl, create-table

This question is inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65868691/create-table-statement-in-oracle).

As stated, I don't want a solution from PL/SQL. I want a 1 or 2 SQL statements that will check for table existence and if its not exist - create it.

Such statement(s) will be plugged into C++ application (not a script) and so I want a plain SQL solution. If such solution is not exist (please say so), I'd like to have a simple string I can plug into C++ code and use either `SQLExecute()` or a native Oracle client API to execute such a string.

Trying to google for a solution I am getting a results that can be used either in the shell script or a stored procedure. As I explain here and in the previous question - my situation is completely different - I work in C++ and want an appropriate solution.

Comment: That's the joy of Oracle.  For a lot of problems, the answer is stored procedures.  And no database solution is "C++ only" ... you rely on the database for stuff, this is just another case.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer, so how do I do it with Oracle?I already have a solution for other DBMSes...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue.  If you're using raw ODBC calls, you can pass an anonymous PL/SQL block to `SQLPrepare` just as you'd pass a pure SQL statement.  PL/SQL seems like an entirely appropriate solution.  You can, of course, take the individual SQL statements from a PL/SQL block and execute them sequentially from your application.  In this case, query `dba_|all_|user_tables` to find out if the table exists and then conditionally execute the DDL.

Comment: @JustinCave, so there is simple `plain SQL` solution? As I said - I will take PL/SQL solution if there is no 1 or 2 plain SQL statements. Also, right now I am writing the ODBC solution, but planning to use native client next. Now what 2 queries you were talking about?

Comment: @Igor - I posted an answer.  Whether you're using ODBC or another client, you can pretty much always use an anonymous PL/SQL block wherever you'd use a SQL statement.  I

Comment: @JustinCave, just saw that. Thank you. I will look into that.

Comment: This is a (rephrased) repost of a closed question being discussed on meta. [CREATE TABLE statement in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65868691/create-table-statement-in-oracle)

Answer (score 2):

There is no single SQL statement that will create a table only if it does not exist in Oracle 11g.

It is not obvious to me why you're objecting to a PL/SQL based solution.  If you're using raw ODBC calls in C++, you can pass a PL/SQL block to `SQLPrepare` just as you would pass a plain SQL statement.  Given that PL/SQL blocks work almost exactly like a pure SQL statement, it would be unusual to categorically reject a PL/SQL based solution.

If you are going to categorically reject PL/SQL, you can certainly take the logic from any of the PL/SQL based solutions and implement that in a couple of SQL statement executed from your application.  For example, you can query `dba_| all_| user_tables` (depending on your privileges, whether you are creating tables in other schemas, etc.) to determine whether the table exists and then conditionally execute your DDL

```
select owner, table_name
  from dba_tables
 where owner = <<schema that will own the table>
   and table_name = <<name of the table>>
```

If that returns no rows you can then execute your DDL.

Of course, you can also just execute your DDL statement and catch the ORA-00955 name is already used by an existing object error in C++.